# Composer Reading Wrong Composer.json Through Jenkins

Tags: php, build, ant, phpunit, composer-php

I have two servers, one for development, one for Jenkins. I'm using PHP 7.0.9 on the dev, and PHP 7.0.9 with Xdebug on Jenkins. When I attempt to build, one of the first steps is to run composer and install my project's dependencies before all the tests run. The strange part about this is it finds the composer.json in my project root, but then proceeds to run the `composer.json` I used on the Jenkins server (in the Jenkins user home dir) which ends up installing nothing.

Here's my full `build.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="GAPCMS" default="full-build">
 <!-- By default, we assume all tools to be on the $PATH -->
 <property name="pdepend" value="pdepend"/>
 <property name="phpcpd"  value="phpcpd"/>
 <property name="phpcs"   value="phpcs"/>
 <property name="phpdox"  value="phpdox"/>
 <property name="phploc"  value="phploc"/>
 <property name="phpmd"   value="phpmd"/>
 <property name="phpunit" value="phpunit"/>

 <!-- Use this when the tools are located as PHARs in ${basedir}/build/tools
 <property name="pdepend" value="${basedir}/build/tools/pdepend.phar"/>
 <property name="phpcpd"  value="${basedir}/build/tools/phpcpd.phar"/>
 <property name="phpcs"   value="${basedir}/build/tools/phpcs.phar"/>
 <property name="phpdox"  value="${basedir}/build/tools/phpdox.phar"/>
 <property name="phploc"  value="${basedir}/build/tools/phploc.phar"/>
 <property name="phpmd"   value="${basedir}/build/tools/phpmd.phar"/>
 <property name="phpunit" value="${basedir}/build/tools/phpunit.phar"/> -->

 <!-- Use this when the tools are managed by Composer in ${basedir}/vendor/bin
 <property name="pdepend" value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/pdepend"/>
 <property name="phpcpd"  value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcpd"/>
 <property name="phpcs"   value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpcs"/>
 <property name="phpdox"  value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpdox"/>
 <property name="phploc"  value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phploc"/>
 <property name="phpmd"   value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpmd"/>
 <property name="phpunit" value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/phpunit"/> -->
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="bin" />

<target name="composer" description="Installing composer dependencies">
 <exec executable="composer" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="install" />
  <arg value="-d" />
  <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
  <arg value="--no-dev" />
  <arg value="--prefer-dist" />
  <arg value="--no-progress" />
  <arg value="--no-interaction" />
  <arg value="--no-scripts" />
  <arg value="--optimize-autoloader" />
  <arg value="-vvv" />

 </exec>
</target>

 <target name="full-build"
         depends="prepare,composer,static-analysis,phpunit,phpdox,-check-failure"
         description="Performs static analysis, runs the tests, and generates project documentation"/>

 <target name="full-build-parallel"
         depends="prepare,composer,static-analysis-parallel,phpunit,phpdox,-check-failure"
         description="Performs static analysis (executing the tools in parallel), runs the tests, and generates project documentation"/>

 <target name="quick-build"
         depends="prepare,composer,lint,phpunit-no-coverage"
         description="Performs a lint check and runs the tests (without generating code coverage reports)"/>

 <target name="static-analysis"
         depends="lint,phploc-ci,pdepend,phpmd-ci,phpcs-ci,phpcpd-ci"
         description="Performs static analysis" />

 <!-- Adjust the threadCount attribute's value to the number of CPUs -->
 <target name="static-analysis-parallel"
         description="Performs static analysis (executing the tools in parallel)">
  <parallel threadCount="2">
   <sequential>
    <antcall target="pdepend"/>
    <antcall target="phpmd-ci"/>
   </sequential>
   <antcall target="lint"/>
   <antcall target="phpcpd-ci"/>
   <antcall target="phpcs-ci"/>
   <antcall target="phploc-ci"/>
  </parallel>
 </target>

 <target name="clean"
         unless="clean.done"
         description="Cleanup build artifacts">
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/phpdox"/>
  <property name="clean.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="prepare"
         unless="prepare.done"
         depends="clean"
         description="Prepare for build">
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/phpdox"/>
  <property name="prepare.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="lint"
         unless="lint.done"
         description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <apply executable="php" taskname="lint">
   <arg value="-l" />

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/tests">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>
  </apply>

  <property name="lint.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phploc"
         unless="phploc.done"
         description="Measure project size using PHPLOC and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line.">
  <exec executable="${phploc}" taskname="phploc">
   <arg value="--count-tests" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phploc.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phploc-ci"
         unless="phploc.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Measure project size using PHPLOC and log result in CSV and XML format. Intended for usage within a continuous integration environment.">
  <exec executable="${phploc}" taskname="phploc">
   <arg value="--count-tests" />
   <arg value="--log-csv" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
   <arg value="--log-xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phploc.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="pdepend"
         unless="pdepend.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Calculate software metrics using PHP_Depend and log result in XML format. Intended for usage within a continuous integration environment.">
  <exec executable="${pdepend}" taskname="pdepend">
   <arg value="--jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml" />
   <arg value="--jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg" />
   <arg value="--overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
  </exec>

  <property name="pdepend.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd"
         unless="phpmd.done"
         description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="${phpmd}" taskname="phpmd">
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg value="text" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpmd.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd-ci"
         unless="phpmd.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD and log result in XML format. Intended for usage within a continuous integration environment.">
  <exec executable="${phpmd}" taskname="phpmd">
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg value="xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml" />
   <arg value="--reportfile" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd.xml" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpmd.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs"
         unless="phpcs.done"
         description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="${phpcs}" taskname="phpcs">
   <arg value="--standard=PSR2" />
   <arg value="--extensions=php" />
   <arg value="--ignore=autoload.php" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpcs.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs-ci"
         unless="phpcs.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer and log result in XML format. Intended for usage within a continuous integration environment.">
  <exec executable="${phpcs}" output="/dev/null" taskname="phpcs">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
   <arg value="--report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
   <arg value="--standard=PSR2" />
   <arg value="--extensions=php" />
   <arg value="--ignore=autoload.php" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpcs.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcpd"
         unless="phpcpd.done"
         description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="${phpcpd}" taskname="phpcpd">
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpcpd.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcpd-ci"
         unless="phpcpd.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD and log result in XML format. Intended for usage within a continuous integration environment.">
  <exec executable="${phpcpd}" taskname="phpcpd">
   <arg value="--log-pmd" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
  </exec>

  <property name="phpcpd.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit"
         unless="phpunit.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
  <exec executable="${phpunit}" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit">
   <arg value="--configuration"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/phpunit.xml"/>
  </exec>

  <property name="phpunit.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit-no-coverage"
         unless="phpunit.done"
         depends="prepare"
         description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit (without generating code coverage reports)">
  <exec executable="${phpunit}" failonerror="true" taskname="phpunit">
   <arg value="--configuration"/>
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/phpunit.xml"/>
   <arg value="--no-coverage"/>
  </exec>

  <property name="phpunit.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpdox"
         unless="phpdox.done"
         depends="phploc-ci,phpcs-ci,phpmd-ci"
         description="Generate project documentation using phpDox">
  <exec executable="${phpdox}" dir="${basedir}/build" taskname="phpdox"/>

  <property name="phpdox.done" value="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="-check-failure">
  <fail message="PHPUnit did not finish successfully">
   <condition>
    <not>
     <equals arg1="${result.phpunit}" arg2="0"/>
    </not>
   </condition>
  </fail>
 </target>
</project>
```

Here's the Jenkins console output on a build:

```
    19:54:43 composer:
19:54:43      [exec] Changed CWD to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GAP CMS Beta/src
19:54:43      [exec] Reading ./composer.json
19:54:43      [exec] Loading config file ./composer.json
19:54:43      [exec] Checked CA file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt: valid
19:54:43      [exec] Executing command (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GAP CMS Beta/src): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
19:54:43      [exec] Executing command (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GAP CMS Beta/src): git describe --exact-match --tags
19:54:43      [exec] Executing command (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GAP CMS Beta/src): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
19:54:43      [exec] Reading /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/composer.json
19:54:43      [exec] Loading config file /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/composer.json
19:54:43      [exec] Reading /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GAP CMS Beta/src/vendor/composer/installed.json
19:54:43      [exec] Reading /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
19:54:43      [exec] Running 1.2.0 (2016-07-19 01:28:52) with PHP 7.0.9 on Linux / 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
19:54:43      [exec] You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
19:54:43      [exec] Reading ./composer.lock
19:54:43      [exec] Loading composer repositories with package information
19:54:43      [exec] Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
19:54:43      [exec] Reading ./composer.lock
19:54:43      [exec] Resolving dependencies through SAT
19:54:43      [exec] Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
19:54:43      [exec] Analyzed 67 packages to resolve dependencies
19:54:43      [exec] Analyzed 77 rules to resolve dependencies
19:54:43      [exec] Nothing to install or update
19:54:43      [exec] Generating autoload files
```

The working directory looks good in the logs, and it seems to load the right composer.json, but then it switches on me to `/var/lib/jenkins/.composer/composer.json` I can't figure out why it's not using the right file. I don't see any options to force composer use that file either.

One more piece of info. Here's the composer.json in the PROJECT:

```
    {
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/spacenate/surveygizmo-api-php"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "spacenate/surveygizmo-api-php": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    }

}
```

And here's the composer.json I've got for the jenkins user on the Jenkins server:

```
#   /var/lib/jenkins/.composer
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.5.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "*",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "*",
        "phploc/phploc": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 2 composer configurations? Shouldn't the Jenkins `.composer` dependencies be a dev dependency in the `composer.json` configuration i.e. use `require-dev` in the `composer.json`. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev

Comment: The one inside the project contains the dependencies for the project only. The one on the Jenkins server has dependencies that Jenkins needs to operate.

Comment: I think you should think about putting the CI server deps. in `require-dev` of `composer.json`.  It's better to have all the dependencies contained within the project and not littered throughout the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this to work. There's not enough documentation out there on Jenkins/PHP so hopefully, this will help someone else. I added the `vendor` directory to my `.gitignore`. Since the `vendor` directory was part of my repo, Jenkins was pulling it and composer thought everything was fine. One of the dependencies was a submodule, so that folder was empty, and was causing issues where it was being required/included.

To fix my repo I did a git rm and `rm -rf` on the vendor directory. Pushed that with Git, and the composer section of the build was able to install all required dependencies!